# Using PHP If Statement with 2 conditions and Explode Function

Tags: php, explode

Pl advise on PHP IF statement. How to use it twice like where an ad script when count of listing reaches 4th number and 9th number on a page with multiple listing

When used with below code it does not works in.

```
    <?php
    $listings = explode("<hr/>", $list);
    $numberOfListings = count($listings);
    for($i = 0; $i < $numberOfListings; ++$i) 
    {
    if ($i == 4)
    { ?> 

   <some ad script runs in>

    if ($i == 9)

    { ?> 

   <some ad script runs in>

    <?php }
    echo $listings[$i] . "<hr/>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: What's your desired output?
What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you close your first if statement?

Comment: You code seems to be syntaxically wrong, so it can't work, If you close PHP, you're displaying HTML, if you want to resume your script with PHP, you have to open again your PHP scripts with opening tag <?php .
You should also close your statements...

Comment: Check out Krish R's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this, Added `$Reset` variable so every loop >10 it reset the count

```
    <?php
    $listings = explode("<hr/>", $list);
    $numberOfListings = count($listings);
    $Reset =1;
    for($i = 0; $i < $numberOfListings; ++$i) 
    {
        if ($Reset == 4)
        { ?> 

   <some ad script runs in>

   <?php } if ($Reset == 9) { ?> 

   <some ad script runs in>

    <?php }
         echo $listings[$i] . "<hr/>";

         if($Reset>10){
                $Reset =1;
          }
          $Reset++;

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Krish. I have set the reset after 15 as every page is having 15 listing count. Your code works awesome and it was pretty fast response too. Thanks